# Why does upgrading Django 1.7c2 to 1.7c3 create new database migrations?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-migration

This is not a problem so much as a curiosity, but I've looked around and can't find an answer to this.

When I upgraded Django 1.7c2 to 1.7c3 today, Django identified that I needed new migrations (ie doing `./manage.py makemigrations` found new migrations). I've downgraded to confirm that it's definitely 1.7c3 that's caused this.

The full output of `sqlmigrate` is shown for each migration in the pull request over at GitHub: https://github.com/sealevelresearch/sea-level-api/pull/89

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could use [git bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to track down the commit that causes the change.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair - I hadn't used `git bisect` before but it found the two commits responsible. Really helpful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrations were related to unmanaged models and the `related_name` argument to `ForeignKey` models.

The two commits responsible for the new migrations were:

- https://github.com/django/django/commit/72fdd62e93cf8bc3a6bfad4d24b06a474ad56942
- https://github.com/django/django/commit/b5784048e085e8db5d0e959c12278ef727994e98

The discussion can be found on Django's project tracker:

- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23275
- https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23288